# total differentiability

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am currently reading the german mathematics book "Tutorium Analysis 2 und Lineare Algebra 2" by Modler and Kreh.
One exercise concerning differentiability left me a bit confused:

$$xy\frac{(x^2 - y^2)}{(x^2 + y^2)} \qquad \forall (x,y)\neq(0,0)  $$
$$ (0,0) \qquad \forall (x,y) = (0,0)$$

In the book the author argues that the function is not differentiable
if the mixed partial derivatives are different. They use as an explanation the Schwarz Theorem. (But doesnt the Theorem just tell us that the function can not be C2 now?)

On the other hand, in our seminar we concluded that the partial derivates Dx and Dy are continous on R2. But wouldn`t this imply that the function is indeed totally differentiable?

So my question:
Is the stated function totally differentiable and if not is the explanation sufficient, that the partial derivatives are different?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is indeed once differentiable everywhere, with $DT_{(0,0)}=0$ (derivative at the origin is the zero linear transformation). This follows immediately from the definition using limits (if you want a further hint, use the inequality $|xy|\leq x^2+y^2$ (actually we have the stronger inequality $|xy|\leq \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$, but we don’t need this)) and the squeeze theorem.

Talking about Schwarz’s theorem in the context of once differentiability is just silly, and their conclusion is also wrong (are you sure you didn’t misunderstand them?) so…

Comment: Thank you very much! I will gladly add this inequality to my collection :). Also maybe I am misinterpreting their statement, but they definitly conclude that it is not differentiable.

Comment: yea this is a surprisingly powerful inequality. It follows by rearranging $(x-y)^2\geq 0$. And there’s also a “version with $\epsilon$” by applying this to $\sqrt{2\epsilon}x$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\epsilon}}y$, to yield $|xy|\leq \epsilon x^2+\frac{y^2}{4\epsilon}$; this comes up a lot when fiddling around with quadratic inequalities (especially in PDEs).

Comment: you can also see the inequality as an immediate consequence of the specific young inequality.